# python add http:// to url open sys args

Tags: python, sys, urlopen

Very new to python, I'm trying to take in a command line argument which is a website and set it to a variable. I use the line below to do this.

`sitefile = ur.urlopen(sys.argv[1])`

The problem is it only works when formatted perfectly in the command line as 'python filename.py http://mywebsite.com/contacts.html'. I want to be able to drop the http://. I've tried the following 2 ways:

```
sitefile = ur.urlopen(sys.argv[1].startswith('http://'))
```

gets error message: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'timeout'

```
sitefile = 'http://' + (ur.urlopen(sys.argv[1]))
```

gets error message: ValueError: unknown url type: 'mywebsite.com/contacts.html'. It appears to just ignore the first half of this concat.

Comment: Read the docs, `startswith` doesn't do what you think: `sitefile = ur.urlopen('http://' + sys.argv[1])`

Comment: `startswith()` returns a bool if the string starts with the arg, so not what you are looking for. You need to add the `'http://` before passing to `ur.urlopen()`. Try `ur.urlopen('http://' + sys.argv[1])`

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What's the ur? give the complete code.

`sys.argv[1].startswith('http://')` return a bool object, drop the `http://` should use `sys.argv[1].replace('http://', '')`.

I think the code should like the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import sys
import urllib2

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print('usage: {} <url>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit()
url = sys.argv[1]

req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print(req.read())
```

Comment: ur is set to import urllib.request it appears to be a simple concat syntax error as the previous comments solved my issue